# ant build change a file without rebuild entire project

Tags: java, ant, build

I have a config file that is very large and I do not wish to change its content.

Whenever I tried to change a file, I have to rebuild the entire war package. Which this could cause a large amount of time loss due to large codebase. I was wondering if I can just change a jar of the class that I have changed?

For example if I could just use native javac and generate the class file and copy/replace to the jar without rebuilding the entire project. Would that work? will it impact my other class files?

If the above generate a different result are there any alternative that I could use without changing the configuration for generating the war package?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy separate jar files in your project:

I assume you use Tomcat:

- Go to the webapps directory.
- Remove the .war
- copy over your changes to the webapps/yourapp directory using rsync (for example).